# MATE 16.04 touchpad xinput (Just want a basic mouse pad) can't disable tapping, scrolling, swiping

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch

I have been attempting this for weeks to turn off every non-basic gesture (I just wan't the touch pad to control the cursor position)

No tapping - there are left and right mouse buttons for that

no swiping/dragging - this dangerously throws icons around or grabs my code text

no scrolling - there are scroll bars and up/down keys for that

Sometimes the mouse just goes nuts and races across the screen in any direction super fast, copying things,creating new folders, rearranging text and causing mayhem. Other times the mouse just sits there and wont move - as if it is waiting for some kind of gesture to proceed (It will momentarily ignore finger movements)

nothing has worked (no change whatsoever)

---

I'm on a Dell Latitude 14 Rugged Extreme (7404) Product Name: 031MTV

Running mate desktop 1.16.2

**I have no touchpad UI settings**

---

This is my `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf`

```
# Match on all types of devices but tablet devices and joysticks
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput keyboard catchall"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        Option "Tapping" "off"
        Option "ClickMethod" "none"
        Option "NaturalScrolling" "false"
        Option "ScrollMethod" "none"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchscreen catchall"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection
```

This is `xinput list`

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ eGalax Inc. USB TouchController           id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse                id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Keyboard                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL Wireless hotkeys                     id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

This is `xinput list-props "eGalax Inc. USB TouchController"`

```
Device 'eGalax Inc. USB TouchController':
    Device Enabled (143):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (145): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Calibration Matrix (281):  1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Calibration Matrix Default (282):  1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (283):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (284):   0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (263): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (264):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (265):    0, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (285): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (286): 0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (287):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (288):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (289):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (290): 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (291): 0
    Device Node (266):  "/dev/input/event9"
    Device Product ID (267):    3823, 1
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (292):   <no items>
    libinput Horizonal Scroll Enabled (268):    0
```

This is `xinput list-props "ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse"`

```
Device 'ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse':
    Device Enabled (143):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (145): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Accel Speed (293): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (294): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (295):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (296):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (297):   1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (283):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (284):   0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (263): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (264):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (265):    0, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (285): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (286): 0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (287):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (288):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (289):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (290): 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (291): 274
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (298):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (299):    0
    Device Node (266):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Device Product ID (267):    2, 5
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (292):   <no items>
    libinput Horizonal Scroll Enabled (268):    0
```

This is `xinput list-props "Virtual core XTEST pointer"`

```
Device 'Virtual core XTEST pointer':
    Device Enabled (143):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (145): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    XTEST Device (260): 1
```

It feels like there is another deeper application that is overriding these settings but that is just a guess (based on no proof). What am I not doing that I should be doing?

Comment: It's always been in the question without editing the question it is already there
- `Running mate desktop 1.16.2`

Comment: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-16-04-lts-reaches-end-of-life/19425 shows your version is EOL.  Support for versions for Ubuntu releases past their Support or "End of Life" (EOL) is off-topic as per https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic   — unless the question is asking how to upgrade to a supported release. You may also consider using an allied Q&A Stack Exchange site, https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @BenMuircroft did you try to change settings in the `mate-mouse-properties`?

Comment: @N0rbert it's written in the question in bold 
- 'I have no touchpad UI settings'